# Encrypt a string in PHP using "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" cypher, encode the encrypted bytes to base64 bytes then generate SHS-256 Hex hash from base64 bytes

Tags: php, encryption

Is there a php function that encrypts a string using "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" cypher, then encodes the encrypted bytes to base64 bytes and then generate SHS-256 Hex hash from the base64 bytes?

```
// Generate RSA key pair
$key = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 2048,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));

// Extract public key
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($key);
$pubKey = $pubKey['key'];

// Encrypt plaintext using RSA/ECB/NoPadding cipher
$plaintext = 'Hello, world!';
openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $ciphertext, $pubKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

// Encode encrypted bytes to base64 bytes
$base64_bytes = base64_encode($ciphertext);

// Generate SHA-256 hex hash from base64 bytes
$hash = hash('sha256', $base64_bytes);

echo $hash;
```

In this example, I first generate an RSA key pair using the openssl_pkey_new() function. I then use the openssl_public_encrypt() function to encrypt the plaintext string 'Hello, world!' using the public key from the generated key pair. The resulting ciphertext is stored in the $ciphertext variable.

I then use the base64_encode() function to encode the encrypted bytes to base64 bytes. Finally, we generate an SHA-256 hash using the hash() function and pass the base64 bytes to it.

I obtain the hex digest of the hash using the default hex hash format and store it in the $hex_digest variable. I then print the hex digest to the console.

Comment: Is there a ready-to-use function for your specific requirement? No. Can you write one? Perhaps.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You ask if there is a function to do X, then you show the code for a function that does X. So since you've answered your question, what is their remaining for a prospective answerer to do?